# spring-data-redis giving exception java.lang.VerifyError: on server startup

Tags: java, spring, redis

Error occurred while i'm trying using `Spring-data-redis

```
 java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory, method: afterPropertiesSet signature: ()V) Incompatible argument to function
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at de.hybris.platform.spring.LazyInitOverrideBeanFactoryPostProcessor.forName(LazyInitOverrideBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:90)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
```

My pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- REDIS Drivers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

Spring declaration in xml file. I have not autowired them so far anywhere from any code. With this spring definition context initialization failing. I have above all maven dependencies present in my class path

```
<bean id="jedisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
    <property name="maxTotal"
        value="10" />
    <property name="maxIdle"
        value="10" />
    <property name="minIdle"
        value="0" />
</bean>


<alias name="jedisConnectionFactory" alias="jedisConnectionFactory" />
<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="port" value="6379" />
    <property name="timeout" value="600" />
    <property name="hostName" value="127.0.0.1" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    <property name="usePool" value="true" />
    <property name="database" value="0" />
    <property name="convertPipelineAndTxResults" value="true" />
    <property name="poolConfig" ref="jedisPoolConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

I also tried using the @Bean declaration which is suggested in many other places. But that is also giving same exception.

```
import org.apache.xpath.operations.String;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig;
@Component
public class RedisConfig
{
    @Bean
    JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig()
    {
        final JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(10);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(10);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(6000);
        return jedisPoolConfig;
    }
    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory(final JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig)
    {
        final JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        factory.setPoolConfig(jedisPoolConfig);
        factory.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
        factory.setPort(6379);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(final JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory)
    {
        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }
}
```

Comment: Call this method on 'RedisTemplate. afterPropertiesSet

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: Spring xml where I'm declaring the bean

<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory" />
 </bean>

Comment: Can you show your code? How do you Autowire them?

Comment: @Deadpool Thanks for your help. I have update the post with declaration of the jedisConnection , jedispool and redisTemplate.